# Python Maya UI doesn't resize to fit children

Tags: python, user-interface, resize, window, maya

I have a UI window done in Maya with Python which displays different attributes everytime an item is selected.

I'd like the window to resize (expand and contract) as per the populated children (displayed attributes) in it.

Any ideas ? or any flags I can use ? I tried resizeToFitChildren which doesn't seem to have any effect. Perhaps this should be combined with some other options/flags ?

Thank you!
Sravan

Comment: Let's see some code of a minimal example if you want some answers. On a side note, doing this in `PySide` which is also native in Maya would become a non-issue.

Comment: A sample of what I tried is like this :

`code:

import maya.cmds as cmds
if cmds.window('test', exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI ('test')
cmds.window('test', rtf=True)
cmds.frameLayout()
cmds.button()
cmds.text(label='test')
cmds.textScrollList()
cmds.showWindow(test)

`